# how to go about making sure nested resource user id is associated to order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Issue:** I can change the user_id of the nested resource url to anything id and it still works.  I'm not sure way this is happening and how to avoid this.

thanks to cancancan gem, no1 can see an order that isn't connected to their account for both a buyer and seller.

The issue is, a url, such as,

```
http://localhost:3000/users/1/orders/1/
```

can be changed to:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/121432121423/orders/1/
```

and the same order still appears.

Nested Route:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :orders
  end
```

Models:

```
order.rb
  belongs_to :buyer, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :seller, foreign_key: :seller_id, class_name: "User"
user.rb
  has_many :sales, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "seller_id"
  has_many :purchases, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "buyer_id"
```

CanCanCan model ability:
def initialize(user)

```
  user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
  #Admin
  if user.admin?
    can :manage, :all
  #Seller && Buyer
elsif user.seller? && user.buyer?
      can :manage, Listing, user_id: user.id
      can :read, Listing
      can :manage, Order, buyer_id: user.id
      can :manage, StripeAccount, user_id: user.id
      can :manage, BankAccount, user_id: user.id
      can :manage, User, user_id: user.id

      # can [:read, :update] Order
  #Buyer
      elsif user.buyer?
        can :read, Listing
        can [:create, :read, :edit, :purchases], Order, buyer_id: user.id

  #Guest
      else
        can :read, Listing
        can :create, Order
        can :create, User
      end
    end
```

Note: a seller is automatically a buyer as buyer boolean is set to true on signup. (seller isn't true and must be verified by admin)

How can I make it so in the rare occurrence when a user does happen to change the user_id number, it will block it and show an error?

Is this a model issue or maybe something that can be defined with cancancan? Or something else perhaps?

Comment: How do you load the order in the controller? Can a user see other users order or should the `user_id` always match the current_user's `id`?

Comment: Whether it's a seller or a buyer signed in, the user_id should always match the current_user - and no, if i attempt to see another users order it gets blocked by cancancan.

Comment: When you load the order in the controller like this `User.find(params[…user_id]).orders.find(params[:id])` or `current_user.orders.find(params[:id])` then you can be sure that the order belongs to the user. But I suggest reading about [Shallow Nesting in the Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting), because there is actually no need to have both ids in the URL.

Comment: I tried previously: @user = current_user.orders.find(params[:id]) - but i get the error "ndefined method `orders' for #<User:01243..." --- before i nested the routes, i had it set up where it was just /orders/id --- do you think its best to not nest them? I was really only doing it to keep the urls in order for organizational sake

Comment: Feels to me like you didn't model the associations between the models correctly or used just some other names. Is there a `user_id` on an order? Does an order `belongs_to :user`? Does a user `has_many :orders`?

Comment: It's above.  I split it up depending on who's signed in.  orders table has seller_id and buyer_id.  whoevers user_id owns the listing gets seller_id and whoever user_id buys the listing gets buyer_id... the links work right and the associations SEEM fine and users can't view orders that aren't connected to their user_id.  BUT i already did attempt adding that.. i tried adding the  "belongs_to :user and has_many :orders but that didn't solve it.